# Lenovo M8 FHD - how to enter service mode on a 'wifi only' device?

Tags: lenovo

Apparently theres this thing called 'service mode' or 'engineering mode' for most / some / all ? devices. Was news to me, can anyone tell me how to access this on the titled tablet without a dialer (wifi only).
Many thanks!

I tried app store - MTK engineering mode - says its made for previous versions of android - may not work, why nothing since, it was released late 2019 (or am I missing some big event!) Maybe Lenovo changed their service policies or this is to do with 'treble project'?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve in service mode?

Comment: I want to change the volume steps (granularity)

Comment: ok, I found in /system/default.prop a setting - ro.factory_mode=0 and ro.debuggable=0. I changed both values to 1, saved, rebooted and I have some type of service mode although Iv no clue what or how to do anything with it! I have posts all over the net about trying to get more volume steps on my device, this is turning in to a royal pain in the ass. I cant use this device as a car head unit until I fix these poxy volume steps..bah humbug!